# copilot error : [Error] An error occurred for 'ReturnKeyCommandArgs'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

When I want to use comments an error is displayed :

```
[Error] An error occurred for 'ReturnKeyCommandArgs': StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Request getCompletions failed with message: The operation was aborted. à StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__143`1.MoveNext()
```

I have already reinstalled vs 2022 and copilot.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Updating VS fixed it (in my specific case, to 17.2.5).